# Magento - how to overwrite EAV resource classes?

Tags: php, magento

Anyone found a way to overwrite eav_resource ? In particular

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rewrite the eav/entity_attribute resource model like any other resource model:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <eav_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <entity_attribute>Your_Module_Model_Eav_Resource_Entity_Attribute</entity_attribute>
            </rewrite>
        </eav_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

Proof of concept:

```
echo get_class(Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute'));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks - did exactly that, but found out that the reason my overwrite was not working was because method in question was called from a child class - in this particular case Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Attribute .

Comment: So anyone looking to tap into attribute options saving should look for Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Attribute::_afterSave instead of Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute::_saveOption

Answer (score 0):

As @srgb said, override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Attribute` `_afterSave` method, and instead of `parent::_afterSave` call your custom module resource class which will extend `Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute`. Here you can override `_saveOption` method.